# How do I structure my tests to accommodate thousands of permutations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a few models in my Rails 4 site that I am unit testing. A `Clazz` can have many `Student`s through the `Enrollment` model.

In order to properly unit test `Clazz`, I need to create thousands of different permutations of types and quantities of classes, enrollments, and students. Using `.yml` will be prohibitively cumbersome in this respect so I think I need to create a factory helper method. I know some people cry foul when creating new logic just for tests but I dont see a way around it.

In my factory method, I have created the objects with `.new` (i.e. `Clazz.new()`) because I intend the models to be used in only one test each. However, since the models are created with `.new`, my `ActiveRelation` code in the models is not working properly. For example

```
class Clazz
    def cash_enrollments
        enrollments.where(payment_type: 'cash')
    end
end
```

This `cash_enrollments` method returns zero records in my tests since my objects aren't in the database.

**How should I handle these tests?**

If I use `.create`, then I should delete all the models that were used in that test when I am done with them in order to keep the data set in a known state, correct? That seems tedious and error prone.

If I don't use `.create`, then how do I build these objects so that I dont need to rewrite my model code by adding in a bunch of `.to_a` calls that would surely cause a degradation in performance?

Comment: Why do you need *thousands* of combinations, again?

Comment: The logic to determine the price of a class is very complicated, with over a dozen different inputs - class size, class type, student type, payment type that the student used, free admissions, who is teaching the class, if the class is sponsored, etc...

Comment: Oh, I see. :/ Well, can't you use `FactoryGirl` then?

Comment: I wasn't aware of FactoryGirl. I will look into it. I already have about 800 tests and 4000 assertions. We just received a new requirement (YAY!) that could result in the number of tests increasing by a factor of 2x, 4x, 8x or more.

Comment: Seems like stubbing the relations would be most effective and efficient. I'd create a grid of inputs and expected outputs. Use the inputs to stub the appropriate relations and check the output matches expected.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `FactoryGirl` looks very impressive. Thanks for suggesting it. I see that it calls `.save!` when creating models. Per my original concern, should I delete these models after I finish each test?

Comment: @mcl You are suggesting that I create a data set and build up the models based upon the properties of the data set, right? That seems very clean and scalable. I like that, and will probably try to implement that. However, I don't think it addresses my concerns in my final two paragraphs.

Comment: @Jeff: see also `database_cleaner` gem. It will handle cleanup after each test.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm suggesting using stubs/mocks to avoid the DB altogether. FactoryGirl would help a lot here. You could also look at memoizing some of your objects that need to be reset before each permutation.

Comment: Given the complexity of your logic, it may make more sense to refactor it into smaller 'bite-size' components that can be unit tested individually.  You can't keep introducing factors that double the count of your tests and still consider it maintainable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, FactoryGirl made it very easy to create the many different scenarios I needed. If you want to write up those suggestions as an answer for the sake of posterity, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need many different combinations of object, I suggest you look into FactoryGirl. You can define several basic objects and tweak them for every test if needed. Say, you have a user factory

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:name) {|x| "user #{x}"}
  balance { 0 }
  email_confirmed { true }
end
```

You can create this basic confirmed user with no money:

```
u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Or you can make him wealthy, just this one instance:

```
wealthy_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, balance: 1_000_000)
```

Or you can unset "confirmed" flag. Or do anything else. You get the idea.